# Is annihilation easy to observe?

Tags: antimatter

It is said that if matter touches antimatter they annihilate in a moment, but...
Electrons and protons have opposite charges... but they don't touch themselves, just creates atom. Why we expect matter and antimatter to annihilate in a moment? Is touching opposite charged particles possible? Shouldn't electron and anti-electron form some kind of atom-like structure? (the same may be said about other particles) Is touching particles possible in typical situation? If not, how annihilation could be possible without additional energy? (example: touching electrons and protons requires a lot of energy in nuclear fusion, even they has opposite charges)

Comment: The atom-like structure is called positronium. But it iless favourable than annihilation.

Comment: The lifetime of positronium is typically a microsecond or so. This a very long time as far as subatomic reactions go. Many take place is much less than a nanosecond.

Comment: Easy to observe? Ever had a PET scan?

Comment: Why positronium annihilates, since its parts doesn't touch each other?

Comment: They have a nonzero probability of being at the same point.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the opposite charges that make antiparticles annihilate: there are electrically neutral particle-antiparticle pairs such as neutrinos and antineutrinos (and neutral particles that are their own antiparticles, like $\pi^0$). What really matters is that all of the other quantum numbers (the "type" of particle) have to match in the right way, and numbers that are conserved such as charge and baryon number remain unchanged.

A proton has charge +1 and the electron charge -1, but the proton also has baryon number +1 and the electron baryon number 0. Since the baryon number is preserved in interactions there is no way for the two to annihilate (what about K-capture? that preserves baryon number by making a neutron: $p^+ + e^- \rightarrow n^0 + \nu^0_e$).

Whether a particle interaction happens depends on the cross-section of the reaction, which in turn depends on how many possible states the products can be in ([Fermi's "golden rule"](https://web2.ph.utexas.edu/%7Eschwitte/PHY362L/QMnote.pdf)). Obviously it also depends on whether the particles "touch". However, in quantum mechanics things don't have definite locations. The probability of observing a particle somewhere is the square of the wave function magnitude, $|\psi(x)|^2$, and the probability of annihilation of two particles will (roughly) also be proportional to how much probability there is for them to be close to each other.

In the case of [positronium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium) where there is an $e^+, e^-$ pair in the ground state they both have identical individual location distributions. They still don't annihilate instantly, and in fact it depends on their spins: when they are opposite (para-positronium) the half-life is 0.1244 ns since more photon states match the total zero spin, while for the case where the spins are aligned (ortho-positronium) the half-life is 142 ns since there are fewer photon states that match the spin 1 state.

Comment: Interesting... does it mean that hot positronium gas shouldn't anihilate? (particles should occupy higher stages, so the cross probability function should be 0 in neighborhood of oposite particle)

Comment: They tend to cascade down to the ground state pretty quickly, so a hot positronium gas is likely not too stable - especially since different pairs will bump into each other.

Answer (score 1):

First, electron and proton do «touch» each other in Hydrogen. The electron ground state «probability cloud» has its maximum density in the atom center. But since proton-electron reaction probability (or how it is called by physicists, cross section) is very low, atom lifetime is very huge. Roughly speaking, electron just flies trough proton. Still, sometimes proton-electron reaction happens (mostly in big atoms with many protons), and it is called "electron capture" or "K-capture".

Electron and positron also form atomic-like structure, positronium. But annihilation reaction cross section is very large, and positronium lifetime is very short.